# Правильная пунктуация в предложении с двоеточием и прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация

> Я не спорил. Всё моя вежливость: нет бы ответить: «Простите, не
>   стану», ну или хотя бы: «Меня это не интересует».

Интересует, как правильно оформить пунктуацию второго предложения, если его не перестраивать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не перестраивать, то:

*Я не спорил. Всё моя вежливость: нет бы ответить «простите, не стану», ну или хотя бы «меня это не интересует».*

Comment: Пожалуй, идеально, спасибо